# How do you apply sodium silicate to a ceramic bowl to achieve a cracked effect?

Tags: ceramics, technique-application

How do I properly apply sodium silicate to a ceramic bowl to achieve the type of effect seen in the image below? I know that I need to apply it after I have opened the hole in the bowl on the wheel, but then what are the next steps?

[image]

Comment: Hi Joachim it is my photo. I purchased this pot some years ago and I'm trying to replicate the effect on the outside of the pot.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the update :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pull your clay into the cylinder you want, scrape off the excess moisture/slip on the outside of the cylinder with a rib. Apply the sodium silicate solution with a paintbrush (to your turning cylinder) where you want the crackles. The heavier the application the larger the crackles (1 coat = fine crackles, etc.) Then dry the sodium silicate on the outside of the cylinder with a heat gun, hairdryer, or torch while turning until dry to the touch. Then push out/stretch the clay from the inside of the cylinder to form your piece.

If your crackles are tiny, you might try drying it a little bit more before stretching again.